# How do I put distinct values from a LINQ query into a list?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I've looked at several answers to similar questions, but none of them solve my problem. All I need to do is get distinct values from a LINQ query (that queries a XML file) and put them into a list. Here is what I have tried:

```
 var XmlData = XDocument.Load("PathToFile");
    List<string> XmlItems = new List<string>();

    var XQuery = from m in XmlData.Root.Elements()
                 where m.Attribute("Category").Value.ToString().Equals("TheCategory")
                 select (m.Attribute("TheAttribute").Value).Distinct().ToString();

    XmlItems.AddRange(XQuery);

    foreach (var item in XmlItems)
    {
        ComboBoxTeams.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

The `Distinct()` function call is not giving the expected result. I'm unfamiliar with how to get distinct values from a LINQ query. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sure the Distinct call is working.  It just isn't giving you what you expect it to.  Can you supply some sample input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point, your `Distinct`

```
var XQuery = from m in XmlData.Root.Elements()
             where m.Attribute("Category").Value.ToString().Equals("TheCategory")
             select (m.Attribute("TheAttribute").Value).Distinct().ToString();
```

is only for `(m.Attribute("TheAttribute").Value)`, not for the whole statement

You may need to change it to

```
var XQuery = from m in XmlData.Root.Elements()
             where m.Attribute("Category").Value.ToString().Equals("TheCategory")
             select (m.Attribute("TheAttribute").Value.ToString()); //get everything first, ToString probably needed
var XQueryDistinct = XQuery.Distinct(); //get distinct among everything you got
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. I can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: @ic3man7019 I can pretty much understand it, because such mistake is typically the harder to spot - especially by the coder himself. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have the .ToString() and .Distinct() in the wrong places.

```
var XmlData = XDocument.Load("PathToFile");
List<string> XmlItems = new List<string>();

var XQuery = from m in XmlData.Root.Elements()
             where m.Attribute("Category").Value.ToString().Equals("TheCategory")
             select (m.Attribute("TheAttribute").Value).Distinct().ToString();

XmlItems.AddRange(XQuery);

foreach (var item in XmlItems)
{
    ComboBoxTeams.Items.Add(item);
}
```

becomes:

```
var XmlData = XDocument.Load("PathToFile");
var XmlItems = (from m in XmlData.Root.Elements()
                 where m.Attribute("Category").Value.ToString().Equals("TheCategory")
                 select (m.Attribute("TheAttribute").Value.ToString())).Distinct();

foreach (var item in XmlItems)
{
    ComboBoxTeams.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because of this line: `XmlItems.AddRange(XQuery);
`. I'm not sure what the `Distinct()` function is doing to the result, but it is invalid to do it this way. It says that the best overloaded match for the list has some invalid arguments.

Comment: I thought the same thing at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of simple values, you need to remove the use of Distinct in your select and put after.

```
var XQuery = (from m in XmlData.Root.Elements()
             where m.Attribute("Category").Value.ToString().Equals("TheCategory")
             select (m.Attribute("TheAttribute").Value.ToString())).Distinct();
```

If you have complex objects you have two alternatives:

Using [morelinq](https://github.com/morelinq) you can use DistinctBy:

```
XmlItems.DistinctBy(x => x.WhateverProperty);
```

Otherwise, you can use a group:

```
XmlItems.GroupBy(x => x.idOrWhateverOtherProperty)
      .Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
var uniqueList = yourList.Distinct().ToList();
```

after you got your non-unique list.